# Youtube full screen shows under the Wordpress layout elements (Chrome only)

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, youtube

Youtube full screen shows under the Wordpress layout elements like menu and footer (Google Chrome browser only).

[image: http://i.imgur.com/mvYqa3U.png]

How can i fix this?

Comment: Could you show what CSS is used for the menu? Or could you perhaps look at the page using the developer tools and see what spaces should be occupied by the elements?

Comment: @EWit - `http://sundance.pl/film-hydroterapia-terapia-spa/` here, take a look. Try to play it with Chrome browser.